# How to pass output of a single to a completable in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I want to call an API `api1` and pass the output returned by the API to a second API `api2`. The first API is a get request and second API is a `POST` request. Therefore, the `api1` returns a `Single<String>` and `api2` returns a `Completable`.

The functions look something like this:

```
// api1
public Single<String> getToken() {
  ...
}
// api2
public Completable saveTokenToBackend(String token, String userId) {
 ...
}
```

I want to chain both of these operations together. The subscriber is only interested in knowing if the process of getting token and saving it was successful or not. Therefore, the return type of the final chain of operations should be a `Completable`. However, when i do this the API calls for `api2` stop happening. Only `api1` works successfully as per logs.

```
Single<Completable> r1 = getToken().map(t -> saveTokenToBackend(t, userId));
Completable r2 = Completable.fromSingle(r1);
```

**My broader question here is that how do i chain a response from a Single to a Completable?**

**Second question is why the above code is not working?**

**::EDIT::**

Based on suggestions in comments, I tried:

```
public Completable getAndSaveToken() {
    getToken().flatMapCompletable(t -> saveTokenToBackend(t, "dummyuser");
}
```

In my application code i am doing:

```
getAndSaveToken()
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(() -> {
                Log.v(TAG, "call success");
    }, error -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error", error);
    });
```

Results in: `java.io.IOException: Must not be called on the main application thread`

Comment: `single.flatMapCompletable((response) -> completable)`?

Comment: I tried doing this and my code started throwing error `Must not be called on the main application thread`. However when i subscribe to the Completable i am doing `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. Not sure whats happening.

Comment: :D well yes the code shouldn't be called on the main thread! But that is a completely separate issue

Comment: As mentioned, i am not subscribing on a different scheduler. I have individual calls to Single and Completable working fine. `flatMapCompletable` is doing something which i don't understand probably. Any hints?

Comment: Something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808411/rxjava-2-flatmapcompletable-is-not-waiting-for-the-completable-to-finish

Comment: You probably have `observeOn` on the `Single<String` that gets your token.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of chaining right? Check the EDIT i added. I want something like that. If it is not possible, i will be happy to know whats going wrong here.

Comment: Clearly it should be possible, but I still don't know if `getToken()` alters what thread you're running things on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 different problems, composition and scheduling. Context: `getToken` return a single and `saveToken(token)` returns a completable.

**composition**: to compose a single and a completable, as you have already noticed, you can use the flatMap operator, this returns a new completable that first gets the token, and then save it (probably, you'll want to modify the token before saving it ;)

```
getToken().flatMapCompletable(n -> saveToken(n)) // returns a completable
```

If you want to keep it as a single, so you can map it back to the first instance:

```
getToken().flatMap(n -> saveToken(n).toSingleDefault(n)) // returns a single
```

**scheduling**: in android, you must not start a request in the main thread. To avoid it you can use the `subscribeOn` operator, also looks like you have already noticed that

```
getToken().subscribeOn(io()).doOnNext(n -> {/*this should be evaluated in io thread*/})
getToken().subscribeOn(io()).observeOn(mainThread()).doOnNext(n -> {/*this on mainThread*/})
```

If you still get the error, then the `observeOn` or `subscribeOn` has been re-configured somewhere. Need more code to be sure. But anyways, you can assert that both requests are executed in the io thread applying the operator twice:

```
getToken().subscribeOn(io).flatMapCompletable(token -> saveToken(token).subscribeOn(io()))
```

Another alternative, if you are using retrofit, is to apply the `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` using the `createWithScheduler(io())` factory, instead of the default one. This will assert that all requests are created in the io(), so you can combine and prepare the data, and finally apply the `observeOn(mainThread())` to update the UI.

Comment: The last point did the trick. I modified my adapter `create` to `createWithScheduler` and it worked. I still wonder what magic `flatMapCompletable` is doing here. If i call both the API individually they work but not with the operator.

Comment: in your last example `getToken().subscribeOn(io).flatMapCompletable(token -> saveToken(token).subscribeOn(io()))`, you don't need to reapply the `subscribeOn(io)` after each operator

Comment: Yep, this is the "magic" situation, in theory the second subscribeOn should not be necessary but it fails 